# Laravel Mutator and Model Observer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to figure out how I can convert my two form fields of feet and inches into a height attribute with my mutator for my Laravel project.

Right now I'm getting an error that height can't be null so I'm trying to figure why its not being set.

```
// Model 

/**
 * Set the height field for the user.
 *
 * @param $feet integer
 * @param $inches integer
 * @return integer
 */
public function setHeightAttribute($feet, $inches)
{
    return $this->attributes['height'] = $feet * 12 + $inches;
}

// Observer

/**
 * Listen to the User created event.
 *
 * @param  User  $user
 * @return void
 */
public function created(User $user)
{
    $user->bio()->create([
        'hometown' => request('hometown'),
        'height' => request('height'),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how mutators work. The only parameter the method gets is the value you set the field to on creating or updating. So it should be.

```
public function setHeightAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['height'] = $value;
}
```

You should perform the feet and inches conversion before assigning the value in the create method. In this case the mutator is useless. Secondly you need to set the `$fillable` propery in your model to allow assigning values to the fields you're creating.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'hometown', 'height',
];
```

Judging from your error, looks you're passing the feet and inches value in your request input. You can do something like this. Replace the input field names with the actual ones you use.

```
public function created(User $user)
{
    $hometown = request('hometown');
    $height = (request('feet', 0) * 12) + request('inches', 0);

    $user->bio()->create([
        'hometown' => $hometown,
        'height' => $height,
    ]);
}
```